# CABasicAnimation Does not have a member called duration: xcode beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Has CABasicAnimation changed with swift? or is this a bug?

Thought this was weird, considering i'm only getting this error when trying to archive a project, not when running it through devices or the simulator..

```
var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.fromValue = self.progress == 0 ? 0 : nil
let progressNew = Float(progress)
animation.toValue = NSNumber.numberWithFloat(progressNew)

animation.duration = 1

self.progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress
self.progressLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animation")
```